# Invalid SAS token being created for Azure API Management

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-api-management, cryptojs, sas-token

I am trying to create an `SAS Token` to communicate with **Azure API Management Rest API** using JavaScript (Express.js). But using that actually leads me to a `401 Unauthorized`. I am using the following lines of code.

```
//  setting one day expiry time
const expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
const expiryString = expiryDate.toISOString()

const identifier = process.env.AZURE_APIM_IDENTIFIER
const key = process.env.AZURE_APIM_SECRET_KEY ?? ""

const stringToSign = `${identifier}\n${expiryString}`

const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, key)
const encodedSignature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(signature)
    
//  SAS Token
const sasToken = `SharedAccessSignature uid=${identifier}&ex=${expiryString}&sn=${encodedSignature}`
```

The above snippet returns me something like this:
`SharedAccessSignature uid=integration&ex=2021-04-21T10:48:04.402Z&sn=**O8KZAh9zVHw6Dmb03t1xlhTnrmP1B6i+5lbhQWe**=` (Some characters hidden for security, but number of characters is real)

*Note that there is only one trailing **dash** `=` in the above mentioned SAS token, whereas SAS Tokens in all examples and manually created SAS Token from API Management Portal have 2 **dashes** `==`*

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-authentication#ProgrammaticallyCreateToken) of SAS token for Azure APIM, we can see the sample is c# code:

[image]

The difference between the sample and your code is the c# sample uses HMACSHA512 but your code use HMAS256. So I think you also need to use HMACSHA512 in your nodejs. You can do it like:

```
var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', key);
```

You may also need to do `hash.update(text);` and `hash.digest()`, please refer to this [document](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html) about it.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was the issue.

Comment: UPDATE: This deserves to be the final answer. I have also added the full code snippet with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Hury Shen! I also figured out that we don't need `crypto-js` for (as we have to import an external library for that). Node has `crypto` as its native module and we can use that. The following JavaScript snippet works fine.

```
import crypto from "crypto"

const identifier = <YOUR_AZURE_APIM_IDENTIFIER>
const secretKey = <YOUR_AZURE_APIM_SECRET_KEY>

//  setting token expiry time
const expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 29)
const expiryString = expiryDate.toISOString().slice(0, -1) + "0000Z"

const dataToSign = `${identifier}\n${expiryString}`

//  create signature
const signedData = crypto
    .createHmac("sha512", secretKey)
    .update(dataToSign)
    .digest("base64")

//  SAS Token
const accessToken = `SharedAccessSignature uid=${identifier}&ex=${expiryString}&sn=${signedData}`
```